# Delete whole firestore collection with 200Mill documents

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore collection, which contains more than 200 million documents. I wish to delete the whole collection. What would be the fastest way to delete them. I tried deleting it using the firestore console but the deletes are rate-limited at about 80k per hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no magic bullet here to make this faster. Deleting documents requires about the same number of physical writes as initially creating them, so it takes a similar amount of time. Consequently, deleting a lot of documents takes a lot of time.

You can typically speed it up by deleting the document in batches, which is the approach the Firebase CLI takes, and is also the approach taken by the documentation on [Delete data with a Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections). But even then it'll be a `O(n)` operation, taking an amount of time linearly proportional to the number of documents.